# Does finite extent $e(X)$ of a space $X$ imply that the space is compact?

Tags: general-topology

For a space $X$, $e(X)=\sup\{|Y| : Y\;\text{is a closed and discrete subspace of}\; X\}$ is said to be the extent of $X$. If the extent $e(X)$ is finite, then what can we say about the space?

Comment: I'm trying to write a proof, and I'm getting the feeling you're going to want some kind of separation ($T_0$ may even be enough).

Comment: Note that $e(X)$ is finite is not a necessary condition for compactness. $S^1$ is compact, but we can have arbitrarily large discrete subsets ($C_n = \{\frac{2\pi}{k} :  0 \leq k \leq n - 1\}$ is a discrete subset of $S^1$ viewed as $[0, 2\pi] / \{0, 2\pi\}$ with $n$ elements).

Answer (score 5):

**Proposition.** If $e(X)<\infty$ and $X$ is $T_1$ then $X$ is finite.

*Proof:* Suppose otherwise, and let $Y\subseteq X$ be any finite subset of $X$. Then $Y$ is closed, and for $y\in Y$ and any $z\in Y\setminus\{y\}$ there is open $U_z$ such that $y\in U_z$ but $z\notin U_z$. Then $U = \bigcap_{z\in Y\setminus\{y\}} U_z$ is a neighbourhood of $y$ such that $U\cap Y = \{y\}$, so $Y$ is discrete. It follows that $e(X) = \infty$. $\square$

Since $X$ is finite implies $e(X)<\infty$, any non-trivial example isn't $T_1$.

**Not every $T_0$ space with $e(X)<\infty$ is compact:**

Let $X$ be real numbers with open sets of the form $(y, \infty)$, $X$ or $\emptyset$ (this is called right-ordered reals). Then every non-empty closed set in $X$ isn't discrete, so $e(X) = 0$. But $X$ isn't compact since $\{(n, \infty): n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is an open cover of $X$ with no finite subcover.

**Proposition.** If $D\subseteq X$ is a discrete closed subspace of compact space $X$, then $|D|<\infty$.

*Proof:* Since a closed subspace of a compact space is compact, $D$ is compact. Since $\{\{d\}: d\in D\}$ is a cover of $D$ by open sets with no finite subcover, it follows that $D$ is finite.

**Corollary.** If $X$ is compact then $e(X)\leq\aleph_0$.

**Corollary.** If $X$ is infinite, compact and $T_1$ then $e(X) = \aleph_0$.

But we have the following result, which also has to do with closed discrete subspaces.

**Proposition.** Let $X$ be metrizable. Then $X$ is compact if and only if for any closed discrete subspace $D$ of $X$ we have $|D|<\infty$.

*Proof:* If $X$ isn't compact there is a sequence $(x_n)_n$ with no convergent subsequence. Then $F = \{x_n : n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is an infinite closed discrete subspace of $X$.

Comment: If we consider $X=[a,b]$, $a\neq b$, as a subspace of the real line, then $X$ is $T_1$ compact and hence $e(X)<\infty$ but $X$ is not finite.

Comment: @nur note that in definition of $e(X)$ we write supremum, that's because the maximum generally doesn't exist. You can't deduce that there's an infinite closed discrete subspace of $X$ from $e(X)\geq \aleph_0$. And even though such subspace  can't exist in a compact space, we can still have $e(X) = \aleph_0$.

Comment: @NurAlam I've added how compactness relates to closed discrete subspaces, hopefully this clears things up